Incorrectly redirected to login route
I am working on a Laravel website that works correctly on the live server but locally on my laptop one of the public routes that process data always redirects to /login when I visit it.
I've tried googling various things - nothing so far. I've tried using `->withoutMiddleware()' call on the route to remove all middleware but it does not work.
Here is how I've defined the route in web.php:
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/rfid-status', [RFIDController::class, 'status'])
    ->withoutMiddleware(['api', 'csrf', 'auth', 'auth.basic', 'guest', 'throttle', 'sanctum']);

the controller's method is never reached I've placed there die('test');. This is how the method looks atm:
function status(RFIDStatusRequest $request)
{
        die('test');
}

and the RFIDStatusRequest request class:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RFIDStatusRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'tag' => 'required|string|exists:rfids,rfid_unique_id|min:1',
            'status' => 'required|in:available,missing',
            'latitude' => 'required|decimal:1,12',
            'longitude' => 'required|decimal:1,12',
            'altitude' => 'required|integer',
        ];
    }
}

The website is running in Docker locally behind an Apache's reverse proxy. That is why my AppServiceProvider looks like this:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\RFIDService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton(RFIDService::class);

        //$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        //URL::forceScheme('https');
        //URL::forceRootUrl(env('APP_URL'));
    }
}

I've uncommented the code which I think might cause any issue for the moment.
I must have misconfigured something but what?
EDIT 1:
here is the output of php artisan route:list --path=rfid-status:
GET|POST|HEAD       rfid-status ............ RFIDController@status


What is the UR in your view?

please post output of php artisan route:list --path=rfid-status

@krisgjika added the output as an edit to the question. The route url is /rfid-status

route:list also shows the applied middewares of a route

It does not show middleware on any of the routes. @krisgjika

Seems that something is picking back up on your auth middleware?
Have you checked that in your auth isnt broadcasted as a global middleware to where the route would constantly pick it up?
If you have checked all the above: php artisan route:clear and php artisan config:clear
If you ran the above command and verified everything else: try defining the route outside any middleware groups or temporarily remove middleware to isolate the problem.
